# How to turn a multidimensional array into an associative array

Tags: php, sql

I hope I'm not reposting or being redundant here, still groking php arrays. I have a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [field_name] => step_one
        [field_value] => A Message
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [field_name] => message_color
        [field_value] => 
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [field_name] => Submitted Login
        [field_value] => admin
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [field_name] => Submitted From
        [field_value] => 127.0.0.1
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [field_name] => step_one
        [field_value] => Another Message
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [field_name] => message_color
        [field_value] => orange
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [field_name] => Submitted Login
        [field_value] => admin
    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [field_name] => Submitted From
        [field_value] => 127.0.0.1
    )

[8] => stdClass Object
    (
        [field_name] => step_one
        [field_value] => some Other Idea
    )

[9] => stdClass Object
    (
        [field_name] => message_color
        [field_value] => pink
    )

[10] => stdClass Object
    (
        [field_name] => Submitted Login
        [field_value] => admin
    )

[11] => stdClass Object
    (
        [field_name] => Submitted From
        [field_value] => 127.0.0.1
    )
```

)
and I want it to read like this:

```
 Array( 
  Array [0] (
      [step_one] => Message
      [message_color] => 
      )
   Array [1] (
      [step_one] => Another Message
      [message_color] => orange

   )
   Array [2] (
      [step_one] => some other idea
      [message_color] => pink
   )
```

but I have no idea how to get there in php. I've tried array_merge(), and array_combine() but I'm just not getting anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A foreach loop'll do ya just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$reduce = function($input)
{
    $current = 0;
    return array_reduce($input, function($a, $b) use (&$current) {
        isset($a[$current][$b->field_name]) && $current++;
        $a[$current][$b->field_name] = $b->field_value;
        return $a;
    }, array());
};

print_r($reduce($input));
```

Output (I have a smaller dataset):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [step_one] => A Message
            [message_color] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [step_one] => Another Message
        )

)
```

The tweak is to start a new element if in the current index (`$current`) the key already exists.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple loop that will do it.

```
foreach($obj_array as $obj){
    $a_array[$obj->field_name]=$obj->field_value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that Tim! It worked perfectly, but like a dolt, I asked the question wrong. I edited the array structure to illustrate how I would like to form the new array. any insight?

Answer (score 1):

Tim Withers solution or...

```
function gather($arr){
  return array($arr->field_name=>$arr->field_value);
}

$newArr = array_map('gather',$oldArr);
```

With oldArr being the original!